# I need a quick doubt clearance

Tags: real-analysis

Okay.
So I have read that any set $H$ is neighborhood of any point $x$ if for any $\epsilon > 0$

$]x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon[$ is subset of $N$.

So here comes that doubt.

]1,3[ is said to be neighborhood of 2.

But if I take $\epsilon =3$ then the

Set $]x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon[$ will be ]-1,5[ which is not a subset of ]1,3[

So how is ]1,3[  a neighborhood of 2 ?

Comment: It should be: "for _some_ $\epsilon > 0$". Replace "any" by "some" and your doubt should evaporate.

Comment: @quasi I know epsilon must be greater than zero and in this case I have taken epsilon = 3 which is greater than zero.

Comment: Also, even after quasi's correction, $]2,3[$ is not a neighborhood of $2.$

Comment: @user562226 You missed quasi's point. You have the wrong quantifier. It is for some, not for all epsilon. So in order to show it is not a neighborhood, you must show that there is no epsilon that works. You have only provided one.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Pardon me sir that is supposed to be ]1,3[ instead of ]2,3[

Comment: @use562226: To say something is true for _some_ $\epsilon > 0$ doesn't mean it's true for _all_ $\epsilon > 0$. It means there exists at least one $\epsilon > 0$ such that the "something" is true.

Comment: @user562226 Okay, in that case it is a neighborhood

Comment: Ohkay I got it.Even if epsilon is small as hell like .0003 or   0.00004 the set with ]2-0.0003,2+0.0003[ will contain infinite points and this set is also a subset of ]1,3[. And same is for 0.00004 too it's epsilon neighborhood with 2 also has got infinite points and that too in ]1,3[ thus ]1,3[ is neighborhood of 2. Thanks thanks thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly: N is a neighbourhood of x if, for ***some*** $\epsilon>0$, N contains $]x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon[$. Not *any*, but *some*. In other words, N is a neighbourhood of x if there *exists* an $\epsilon>0$ such that N contains $]x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon[$.

> ]2,3[ is said to be neighborhood of 2.

It's not. It doesn't even contain 2.

It's a neighbourhood of 2.5, though. You can't take $\epsilon=3$, but that doesn't matter; you just need *some* $\epsilon$ to work (e.g. $\epsilon = 0.01$ works).

Comment: Pardon me sir that is supposed to be ]1,3[ instead of ]2,3[

Comment: Okay. The same comments apply.